# html2Canvas/jsPDF only converts the data in the viewport to pdf?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, pdf-generation, jspdf, html2canvas

I am trying to use the [html2Canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to convert html content to pdf. I have one consent form which is long and we have to scroll like below.

[image] [image]

I have written below code to convert the consent form into pdf and later show it in a separate screen.

```
let htmlGrid = document.getElementById('customContent');
const options = {background: "white", height: htmlGrid.clientHeight, width: htmlGrid.clientWidth};
html2canvas(htmlGrid, options).then((canvas) => {
let doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
let imgData = canvas.toDataURL("image/PNG");
//Add image Canvas to PDF
doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0);
let pdfData = doc.output('datauristring');
```

But, the problem is that it is converting only the portions of the form which is in view port.
[image]

The portion is getting chopped off which is not in the viewport.

I tried to add below line before converting to pdf but it worked only for browser.

```
htmlGrid.style.height = "auto";
```

It did work for browser but it did not work for android which is a small screen compared to browser.

Is there anything missing the configuration while converting to pdf?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
loadPDF() {
  let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
  h2c(document.getElementById('mybarchart')).then(function (canvas) {
  let width = doc.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
  let height = doc.internal.pageSize.getHeight();
  let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1.0);
  doc.addImage(dataURL, 'jpg', 0, 0, width, height, 'none');
  doc.save(`test.pdf`);
  document.getElementById("pdfLoader").classList.remove('loader');
  setTimeout(() => {
    window.close();
    }, 2000);
  });
}
```